# Is it possible to upload a file to Amazon S3 with just a url?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

For example, let's say I had a URL Link to an image: http://image.com.
Would it be possible for me to use Python to directly upload the image there to S3 without having to save it locally?

Comment: Just wondering, if someone else is hosting the image, why would you want to re-host that?

Comment: I want to store it in S3 just as a central place to keep all of the images stored- named to our own convenience, etc. It would also make it much more accessible to some teammates who will always have access to the images in the S3 bucket, but not necessarily the URL.

Comment: AFAIK There is no way to directly get S3 to read a remote URL (you can copy from one bucket to another but not from an arbitrary URL). But you don't have to store it locally - you can just use the python code to stream the image with [`boto.s3.key.Key.set_contents_from_stream()`](http://boto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.key.Key), this avoids the need to do the checksum/md5, but sacrifices confirming full integrity.

Answer (score 0):

There is no command in Amazon S3 to retrieve a file from a remote location. The API requests require passing the file contents while creating an object.

You could create an **AWS Lambda function** that downloads a file and uploads it to an S3 bucket, and you could put an **API Gateway** interface in front of it. This would give you the ability to make one request with a URL and have the file copied to S3.